# Vue3 hidden input cant not trigger onchange event

Tags: javascript, file, input, vuejs3

Here is my code, im trying to click uploadButton to trigger input changeEvent, i use it in chrome and brave not work, i have no idea why it doesnt work

```
let fileInput = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

const uploadImg = () => {
fileInput.value?.click()
}

const getImageUrl = () => {
console.log('getupload')
}

<input ref="fileInput" type="file" @change="getImageUrl" hidden />
<button class="uploadButton" @click="uploadImg">上傳圖片</button>
```

i want to click button then choose picture and i can trigger change event to get picture information

Comment: [Your code works fine](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Perhaps you've not included all relevant code or provided enough debugging information (error/warning messages or notable behaviors)